# is the stripe session for bank account mode broken

Tags: stripe-payments

Chatted with stripe support and had them test with same results

When using the api via:

```
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ['us_bank_account'],
    success_url: topLevelDomain + '/billing_setup/?success=yes&session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
    cancel_url:  topLevelDomain + '/cancel',
    mode: 'setup',
  });
  return Response.redirect(session.url, 303);
```

I then go through the process of connecting a bank account in both sandbox mode and live mode, tested on multiple browsers and incognito.

I successfully connect, but then clicking verify expected outcome is a redirect to the success_url...but instead nothing happens.

Is there another parameter i need to be setting or is this a bug. Chat support was 0 help.

Thanks

Comment: I was able to create set up and verify a bank account in test mode using your code. It would probably be best to write in to Stripe Support again with more detail on what steps you are taking in test mode and what you see after you click "Verify".

Comment: @Pompey to confirm you are using the login method to verify a bank and then after you login it then redirects you to the succuss_url and u are in mode of "setup" and have no other options added?

Comment: @Pompey I made them a video and they confirmed seeing the same issue of no redirect to the success url after loggin into their bank account and then clicking verify, so I am very confused how you are seeing this work

Comment: There was an intermittent Chceckout+ACH issue like this that affected some accounts but not others but it looks like it has been fixed since. Are you still seeing this bugged behavior if you create another Checkout Session and try this flow again?

Comment: @Pompey today it's now working as expected...but def cost 2.5 days of work and no sleep trying find a fix. For future reference, where did you check status to know this or do you work for stripe?